# Mystery hand-tool, what's its use?

Tags: hand-tools, antique

We got this tool from an estate sale. What was its original use? The markings indicate a patent date of Dec 15 1914
there are no makers marks or manufacturer names on it.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you turn the crank?  Does it go up and down?  Vibrate?  Turn?  Fast or slow?   It looks like there is a spring-loaded button on the side of the bell-shaped piece.  Maybe something clips inside there, and the button releases it.  Can you confirm that?  It looks like there is something at the top of the axle or pin ... is that a quick release to separate the axle from the handle?  Can you try or confirm that?

Comment: What happens when you turn the handle?  Wild guess would a hand impact chisel or a bell ringer.

Comment: Assuming that turning the crank causes the bottom part to rotate, my guess would be that it's a device to twist cord into rope, or something similar.

Comment: Agreeing with @HotLicks: See https://picclick.com/Antique-Original-Cast-Iron-AAU-Rope-Maker-and-323584739581.html

Comment: Looks like the first sewer auger.   It should have a cable with a screw-like auger to bite in to sewer blockage . Of course today they are electric powered.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  Interesting to see my name in that link.  Should make it an answer.

Comment: It might be worth cross-posting this on reddit's "whatisthisthing" board; those guys can identify just about anything.  Then we could post the answer here or invite the answerer to do so.

Comment: Did you try a Google Image Search?

Comment: thanks @ Hot Licks, I think that is it, when you turn the crank, yes, the bell shaped portion turns. Thanks @ DrMoishe Pippik, the photo was spot on and really helped. Might be worth a bit!